# Is there a PHP package I can plugin to manage program requests?

Tags: request, bug-tracking, get-satisfaction

I'm just wondering what do you use for managing visitor requests on your website?

Basically, I'm wanting people who use my program to be able to ask for requests, or submit a bug and for people to be able to see those things and vote them up in priority.

ideally this program is lightweight... I've come across programs like The Trac (http://trac.edgewall.org/) which looks amazing, but its more complex then I need this to be.

In my travels, I have seen Get Satisfaction (http://getsatisfaction.com/) which looks perfect and seems to have all the functionality one could desire for a plugin - but for $99 a month I'm erring on the side of not using that.

What do you use? Is there something available out there just as good and simple as get satisfaction without the monthly price tag?

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not [uservoice](http://uservoice.com/)? It was good enough for Stackoverflow to use, and they have a [Free version](https://uservoice.com/account/new/free) :)